# Swift cannont convert value of type 'uiimageview' to expected element type 'string'

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

Not sure there were changes between Swift 1.0 and 2.0 but the following example code isn't compiling and throwing the following error: cannont convert value of type 'uiimageview' to expected element type 'string'

Here is the example code where we are attempting to create an array of images to add to a UIPickerView component.

```
animalImages = [
        UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "mouse.png")),
        UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "goose.png")),
        UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "cat.png")),
        UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "dog.png")),
        UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "snake.png")),
        UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "bear.png")),
        UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "pig.png")),
    ]
```

Comment: You may have declared animalImages as an array of strings earlier in the code. Change the array's type to UIImageView.

Comment: By default, `UIPickerView` expects strings.

Comment: The array was declared as an array of strings and not UIImages.  That did the trick in removing the error. @JanGreve :)

Comment: @LaurenceWingo My comment was aiming towards the tags I already removed for you.

Comment: You have an extra `,` at the end of the last item in the array.

Comment: @JanGreve gotcha!  They always ask for at least five tags which I know could be solved with just the first two to three tags. Apologies

Comment: Comments are ephemeral, so I've made an answer - it may be helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler tells you

> Cannot convert value of type 'uiimageview' to expected element type 'string'

It means that at the location where you're using a UIImageView, the compiler actually expects to find a String.

Why?

Swift is a strongly typed language. It means that when you declare the type of an array, this array will always expect elements of this type.

Then my diagnosis for your issue is that **you probably have declared your array, earlier in the code, as an array of Strings**. Change the type of the array to be [UIImageView] and you'll be ok.